# Powershell reflection run the function

Tags: .net, powershell, reflection

I have this workable code

```
[Windows.Forms.Form].
Assembly.GetType(
    'System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods'
).GetMethod('GetAsyncKeyState').Invoke($null,
    (
        0x09 # Tab key code
    )
)
```

Now im trying to invoke **EnumWindows**

```
$EnumWindowsUtil = [Windows.Forms.Form].
Assembly.GetType(
    'System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods'
).GetMethod('EnumWindows')
    
    
# Create a list to act as a receptacle for all the window handles we're about to enumerate
$WindowHandles = [Collections.Generic.List[IntPtr]]::new()

# Define the callback function
$callback = {
    param([IntPtr]$handle, [IntPtr]$param) 

    # Copy the window handle to our list
    $WindowHandles.Add($handle)

    # Continue (return $false from the callback to abort the enumeration)
    return $true
}

if($EnumWindowsUtil.Invoke($null, ($callback, [IntPtr]::Zero))){
    # $WindowHandles will contain all the window handles now
}
```

The error is:

> Object of type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' cannot be
> converted to type
> 'System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods+EnumThreadWindowsCallback'

How to fix types conflict, and run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit conversion to `[SafeNativeMethods+EnumThreadWindowsCallback]` fails because it's a *non-public* type.

Use the `-as` operator to explicitly convert the scriptblock:

```bsh
$EnumWindowsUtil = [Windows.Forms.Form].
Assembly.GetType(
    'System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods'
).GetMethod('EnumWindows')
   
# Create a list to act as a receptacle for all the window handles we're about to enumerate
$WindowHandles = [Collections.Generic.List[IntPtr]]::new()

# Discover parameter type
$callbackParameterType = $EnumWindowsMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType    

# Define the callback function, convert to parameter type
$callback = {
    param([IntPtr]$handle, [IntPtr]$param) 

    # Copy the window handle to our list
    $WindowHandles.Add($handle)

    # Continue (return $false from the callback to abort the enumeration)
    return $true
} -as $callbackParameterType

if($EnumWindowsUtil.Invoke($null, ($callback, [IntPtr]::Zero))){
    # $WindowHandles will contain all the window handles now
}
```